# Reading bluetooth low energy properties (reading, notifications) - how it works?

Tags: android, properties, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm analyzing a sample from android, which is explaining a bluetooth low energy usage on android. I've found the following code, which is setting a notification, but I can't get what is happening here with using a properties integer and conditions inside ifs. Could someone explain it a little bit?

Anyway, maybe you have some better source, which can explain a ble concept on android- what and how is working here? The official android tutorial is really poor, and bluetooth official page is giving almost nothing...

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                            int childPosition, long id) {
    if (mGattCharacteristics != null) {
        final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic =
                mGattCharacteristics.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
        final int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();
        if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
            // If there is an active notification on a characteristic, clear
            // it first so it doesn't update the data field on the user interface.
            if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                        mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
            }
            mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }
        if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
            mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic;
            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                    characteristic, true);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That sample is really broken in all possible ways. There are probably tons of other examples if you just search the internet.

Comment: @Emil, Yeah there are PROBABLY tons of others examples, but I've tried to find some- and they are complicated in another ways. A lot of them are written in a different way. None of examples/tutorials which I've found is explaining some basics of BLE such as reading from some bits and so on, or just stupid explaining a basic UUID from 16bits creation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reading the Bluetooth specification (https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/adopted-specifications, Core Version 5.0), vol 3 part G. Just note that Android abstracts away the attribute handles.

What most people do however is writing an app designed for a particular hardware, i.e. the gatt db is assumed to be known.

In order to get objects that represents the services, characteristics and descriptors, call gatt.discoverServices(). The result is returned asynchronously using the onServicesDiscovered() callback. This should be done each time a device gets connected (in the onConnectionStateChange callback when newState is GATT_CONNECTED).

To write to a characteristic, first set the value on the BluetoothGattCharacteristic object using the setValue method, then call gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic). When the operation is complete, onCharacteristicWrite will be called.

A read operation works in similar way; call gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic) and the result is ready when the onCharacteristicRead is called. Use getValue() on the characteristic object to get the value.

For notifications to work you must first write BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE (0x0001) to the client characteristic configuration descriptor so that the peripheral will start deliver notifications. You must also tell the Android Bluetooth stack to forward the notifications to your app by calling setCharacteristicNotification.

Note that you can only have one outstanding operation at a time (read/write), meaning you must wait for the callback before you issue a new request.

If you know the hardware you're dealing with you normally don't need to inspect the characteristic properties (characteristic.getProperties()). The bitmask is described in Bluetooth Core V 5.0 specification, Vol 3, Part G, section 3.3.1.1 and describes what features are enabled for each characteristic (for example read, write, notifications).

How to deal with conversion between 16-bit and 128-bit UUIDs is shown in the Bluetooth Core V 5.0 specification, Vol 3, Part B, section 2.5.1. Note that Android's client libraries only use 128-bit UUIDs.